# redux-toolkit does not allow mutating state in createSlice

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

My redux toolkit / immer slice is doing a mutation, but that is allowed, why am i getting the mutation was detected error? Is it my reducer?

```
Error: Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path 'components.component_159275.input.options'.  This may cause incorrect behavior. (https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-mutate-state)
```

```
reduxDispatch(updateValue({ componentId, value }));
```

```
export const componentsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'COMPONENTS',
  initialState: defaultState.components,
  reducers: {
    updateValue(state, action) {
      const { payload } = action;
      const { componentId, value } = payload;
      state[`component_${componentId}`].component.input.value = value;
    },
  },
});
```

I have this rule, in eslintrc to allow param reassign, is there a rule i am missing that i need to add?

```
    "no-param-reassign": [ // allows us to reassign where the param which is used in that is state or ctx.
      "error",
      { "props": true, "ignorePropertyModificationsFor": ["state", "ctx"] }
    ],
```

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Interesting. Can you put a breakpoint in `updateValue` and check the type of `state`? And how do you import/export the action creator `updateValue` that you use in the `dispatch` line?

Comment: Also eslint has nothing to do with the error, what you are getting is a runtime error.

Comment: What is `component` here? What kind of value is it? Where is it coming from when it's added to the state?

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie 
- I don't have a debugger in vscode as its frontend side of a dockerized project which i / my lead wasn't able to create a launch file for.  
- Logging the action shows the expected payload, i can't log state. 
- updateValue is a named import  where it is used, it console logs prior to the dispatch, but the error occurs at invocation of the function.

Comment: @markerikson component is a react form input component, they vary, but there is always an input value hence this reducer.

Comment: @Jeremy : if you're saying that's a literal DOM node, **DON'T DO THAT!  You must _never_ put DOM nodes or other non-serializable values into Redux!** https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions

Comment: @markerikson no no, its not literally a dom node, its data for a react input component serialized by id i.e. component.input.value is value for a component which gets built in the app (depending on component.type... i.e. textfield / radio etc) - data for values come from a backend via a gateway and we have an array of these values in redux. Its pretty complex.

Comment: The original error message says that it's a `.input.options` field that got mutated - I would recommend checking where you access that `.options` field.

Comment: The error isn't saying that the "mutation" you are doing in the reducer is the problem. No, it's informing you that your Redux state was ***externally*** mutated between renders/calls. Like @markerikson says, check your UI where you are selecting this "COMPONENTS"` state and scour *that* code for mutations. Finding state mutations can be tricky since anything with a reference to anything in the state can mutate it. If you are mixing old "legacy" reducers with RTK slices, you may even need to scour that code.